# Where can I find a complete list of format specifiers for the date command?

Tags: date, man, macos

I wanted to get the month name on macOS 11.6, and I tried

1. checking the man page of `date`
2. checking the man page of `strptime`

But I couldn't figure out what format specifier to use to display the month name.

After searching the internet, it seems that `%b` displays it.

I would like to know, where can I find all the information about specifiers within UNIX?

What's the official source, if man page doesn't have this info?

Comment: The One Official Source is the source of the `date` program. It's FOSS, after all.

Comment: It's worth noting that most versions of the `date` command accept at least one more format specifier than `strftime` does, namely `%s`, to print a raw `time_t` value (seconds since 1970)..

Comment: `strftime`, at least on macOS, is documented as accepting `%s`.

Answer (score 13):

The manual for the C language function `strftime()` (`man strftime`) should contain all the date format specifiers across most Unix and Unix-like systems.

The `strptime()` function has to do with parsing strings into time values (which is not what you want to do), whereas `strftime()` has to do with outputting time values as formatted strings (which you want to do).

See also [the POSIX specification for the `strftime()` interface](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html).

Answer (score 9):

MacOS is [POSIX compliant](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/), and is certified as such. Therefore you can also check the [POSIX documentation for `date`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/date.html). Here it does list the available format specifiers:

> **Conversion Specifications**
>
> **`%a`** Locale's abbreviated weekday name.
>
> **`%A`** Locale's full weekday name.
>
> **`%b`** Locale's abbreviated month name.
>
> **`%B`** Locale's full month name.
>
> ...

It's a shame that the Mac's man page omits this useful information directly. However, it does contain this paragraph:

> An operand with a leading plus (`+`) sign signals a user-defined format string which specifies the format in which to display the date and time. The format string may contain any of the conversion specifications described in the *strftime*(3) manual page, as well as any arbitrary text. A newline (`\n`) character is always output after the characters specified by the format string.

In the SEE ALSO section there is also a reference to *strftime*(3).

Unfortunately, on my Mac at least, there is no *strftime*(3) man page, so it's not possible to get to further information without referencing documentation online. (Apparently the C library man pages are installed as part of XCode.)

Comment: I believe that the `strftime(3)` man page is only present if you have XCode installed.

Comment: The POSIX standard list the formats that an implementation *must* support. It's not necessarily the complete list that an implementation of `date` *can* support.

Answer (score 2):

For the `date` command, `man date`is the right reading. It does list %b and %B, so you should have found it directly, without perusing the internet. [Here's a somewhat recent copy of that `man date`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html).

But that is specific to that command. Other programs, libraries have different formats. You will need to look up their individual documentation.

Comment: on macOs, `man date` doesn't show %b or %B. There is no info on any format specifier.

Comment: @mtk The macOS man page says "An operand with a leading plus (`+`) sign signals a user-defined format string .... The format string may contain any of the conversion specifications described in the strftime(3) manual page, ..." so `man 3 strftime` has the relevant list.

Comment: @GordonDavisson: Your comment should be the accepted answer, since it's the only one showing *the process* of how to get from `man date` to the solution.

Comment: @Heinzi except that on at least my Mac, there is no _strftime_ man page installed

Comment: @roaima That's a separate issue. The man page for `date` specifically refers you to the man page for `strftime`.